# Sending property name to a method

Tags: c#, properties

I have a question, similar to what was asked in the past, but I wonder if there is a way to achieve this:

Sending to a method the name of the property itself, without using the property directly. (IE. Not GetName(()=> ParamSearch1parameter - like seen on another solution)

Example code:

```
#region Props

    public string ParamSearch1
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueFromQueryString(/*Here should come a string called ParamSearch1*/); 

        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helper Methods

    private string GetValueFromQueryString(string keyName)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[keyName]) ? "" : Request.QueryString[keyName];
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Haven't had first coffe yet but, *what*?!

Comment: lol, yeah maybe it is not clear. I'll edit.

Comment: Why not pass just string parameter? GetValueFromQueryString("ParamSearch1");

Comment: Cause of pure laziness. I don't want to change the string with every copy & paste XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're targetting .NET 4.5, you can use the [CallerMemberName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

```
public string ParamSearch1
{
    get
    {
       return GetValueFromQueryString();     
    }
}

private string GetValueFromQueryString([CallerMemberName] string keyName = "")
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[keyName]) ? "" : Request.QueryString[keyName];       
}
```

Otherwise there's no built in solution other than the solutions you've already come across. If you're happy to add an extra dependency, you can use the [MS BCL Portability Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) to provide the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to previous versions of .NET or follow Thomas's post on recreating the attribute in the comments.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to target .NET 4.5. You just need to use the C# 5 compiler, and manually recreate the `CallerMemberName` attribute. I have a blog post about it [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2012/06/13/using-c-5-caller-info-attributes-when-targeting-earlier-versions-of-the-net-framework/), but my site is down right now... working on it.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer, keen on seeing the implementation. I also remembered the BCL pack but never tried it myself.

Comment: There is nothing in the implementation, just the class declaration. These attributes are just markers. https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/326deef9253e3ce4f900